# How to scrape HTML divs that are not children of another div?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have HTML files. for each file, I want to scrape all tables one by one and still have the index of the table to use for getting title and some text before the table.

I used `soup.find_all('divs')` to pull all divs and based on the results I built my application.

When I tried a different HTML file with slightly different format like this:

```
<div style="margin-top:27.85pt;margin-bottom:21.86pt;margin-left:69.66pt;width:456pt;">
<div style="text-align:center; width:456pt; line-height:14pt;font-weight:bold;color:#33058D;font-size:12pt;">UNITED STATES<br/>SECURITIES AND EXCHANGE COMMISSION<br/>Washington, D.C. 20549<font style="font-weight:normal;color:#3D3935;font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif ;letter-spacing:0.24pt;"> </font></div>
<div style="margin-top:12pt; text-align:center; width:456pt; line-height:14pt;font-weight:bold;color:#33058D;font-size:12pt;">SCHEDULE 14A<font style="font-weight:normal;"> </font></div>
<div style="margin-top:8pt; text-align:center; width:456pt; line-height:11pt;">Proxy Statement Pursuant to Section&#160;14(a) of <br/>the Securities Exchange Act of 1934<font style="font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif ;letter-spacing:0.18pt;"> </font></div>
</div>
```

It contains 1 div (parent) and 3 child divs.
`soup.find_all('div')` returns 4 items: 1 parent div with children and each children div in the main div.

I want it to pull the parent div only.

```
divs = []
while len(html) > 0:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    div = soup.find('div')
    divs.append(div)
    length = len(str(div))
    html = html[:len(html)-length]
```

I tried creating this code but it was very very inefficient although the result was exactly as I wanted. It took very long time to finish.

Comment: What is your expected output? _"I want to scrape all tables one by one"_ I hadn't saw any table in your question? You can't `divs`, I believe you want to tell, `div`? And _"the result was exactly as I wanted"_ Are you really getting expected result, then what was the actual question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood correctly, but if the only problem that you have is that you're not sure how to extract just the parent div, you can do it using this css selector: "div:not(div > div)"

This basically specifies selecting all the divs that are not direct children of other divs. Use this along with select from beautifulSoup and it should do the trick.
Here's the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """
<div style="margin-top:27.85pt;margin-bottom:21.86pt;margin-left:69.66pt;width:456pt;">
<div style="text-align:center; width:456pt; line-height:14pt;font-weight:bold;color:#33058D;font-size:12pt;">UNITED STATES<br/>SECURITIES AND EXCHANGE COMMISSION<br/>Washington, D.C. 20549<font style="font-weight:normal;color:#3D3935;font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif ;letter-spacing:0.24pt;"> </font></div>
<div style="margin-top:12pt; text-align:center; width:456pt; line-height:14pt;font-weight:bold;color:#33058D;font-size:12pt;">SCHEDULE 14A<font style="font-weight:normal;"> </font></div>
<div style="margin-top:8pt; text-align:center; width:456pt; line-height:11pt;">Proxy Statement Pursuant to Section&#160;14(a) of <br/>the Securities Exchange Act of 1934<font style="font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif ;letter-spacing:0.18pt;"> </font></div>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
divs = soup.select('div:not(div > div)')
```